# i cant know how two values return at same time from one variable in cpp

Tags: c++

please don't mark as duplicate first read full question i want to know how one variable or function(with return:) return two value at same time

i am printing ASCII values of characters and when i press any arrow key then two values are printed like 224 then in next line 80 printed how it possible that one variable give me two values at same time

i am using GCC on code block in windows 7

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstdlib>

int show;
int main()
{
while(true)
    {
    int show = getch();
    std::cout << show<<std::endl;
    }
getch(); // Just to keep the console open after program execution
}
```

we know that arrow keys are special keys whom return two ASCII value at same time but how one variable can print both values same time

Comment: It's not the case that one variable has two values at the same time. Your code is in a loop, so the variable has two different values **in quick succession**, not at the same. In this example your code goes round the loop twice, with the variable having different values each time round the loop.

Comment: thanks for reply . it mean special keys like arrow keys return two values but getch() function accept it one by one . i mean one value with one loop

Comment: Yes the getch function returns the two values one at a time. What makes you think that's not the case here?

Comment: then please explain

Comment: I already did explain. I'm struggling to understand what you don't understand. Of course a variable can't have two values at the same time. I don't understand why you think that is happening here.

Comment: It's very simple you have a **loop**, and your code goes round the loop **twice**, with a different value for `show` **each time**. `show` does not have two values at the same time.

Comment: Maybe you can try and explain why you don't understand what I've just said, or why you think it is wrong. Because I'm afraid I don't understand.

Comment: I believe you would benefit from learning how to use a debugger. They will show you step by step what happens.

Comment: @john I assume he wants to know why a single keypress generates 2 different characters.

Comment: @IcedLance The last sentence of his question shows that he understands that. (Although maybe not completely).

Comment: for example i am press up arrow key after run then getch assign value to show and show get printed by printf and cursor will go next line then what happen i cant understand .  getch assign  new  value to show or something else is happen

Comment: getch assigns a new value to show.

Comment: I do not think this is a duplicate of set post. @ManpreetSidhu said `i am printing ASCII values of characters and when i press any arrow key then two values are printed like 224 then in next line 80 printed how it possible that one variable give me two values at same time `. You store the value from `getch` inside an integer variable. `std::cout << show << std::endl;` will print 80 if the keypress results in ascii value of 80. If you want the 'character' value simply use `static_cast<char>(show)`.

Comment: @john if getch assigns a new value to show. then how getch provide the value 2nd time because getch accept one character at a time and if it accept one character then after prees any arrow key it accept 80 or 244

Comment: @ManpreetSidhu getch sits in front of a buffer. If there are no bytes in the buffer then getch waits until you press a key. For most keys one byte is added to the buffer which getch then returns and removes from the buffer. But for the up arrow key two bytes are added to the buffer, getch removes and returns the first byte from the buffer, but the second byte remains. So the next time you call getch it will return that second byte (and remove it from the buffer) without waiting for any key to be pressed. That's how getch works.

Comment: @ManpreetSidhu I have to say you are trying to make something very simple into something very complicated. You are probably over thinking things. Your own program is showing you what is happening, and it doesn't need any fantasy like variables having two values at the same time.

Comment: thanks sir your right